# How to install GNOME on Ubuntu Studio?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, ubuntu-studio

Is it possible to install GNOME on Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS?

I have an ASUS X515EA and here are the specs if you need them:

- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz
- Intel Iris Xe Graphics
- 8GB RAM DDR4 Soldered Single Channel

Comment: You can install the Ubuntu Studio system on Ubuntu Desktop (ie. GNOME), or any [other official *flavor* of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) - refer https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-installer/ and the Ubuntu Studio Installer.   Be aware that Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS reaches EOL in April 2023 (*3 years for Ubuntu Studio packages*) and has no upgrade path due to it using the Xfce desktop (*later supported releases no longer use Xfce*)    FYI:  You can install multiple desktops (inc. *flavors*) on a Ubuntu system, but I've little experience with Ubuntu Studio in this regard

Answer (score 2):

A simple way would be to install the ubuntu-gnome-desktop package. At the next login, you'll have the option to log into your usual Ubuntu Studio Plasma desktop environment, or the full Ubuntu Gnome desktop.

But I have had mixed experiences with this approach - Plasma and Gnome tend to step on each other's toes, they assign different default apps for specific tasks, and theming and styling works differently. So this will take some further tweaking to get "right".

A better approach is the one proposed by @guiverc above: do a standard, "vanilla" Ubuntu Desktop install, and then use the [Ubuntu Studio Installer](https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-installer/) to add the components you need/like/use often.

This would give you the best of both worlds.